# How can the height of seaborn boxplots be changed?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, boxplot

Is there a way to change the height in seaborn's boxes in the boxplot in a way to use a custom function instead of the quartiles (SEM, SD...)? Either by a function directly or by a separate column in a dataframe. To clarify that: I want custom boxes, not changes the plot as a whole

Comment: From the [seaborn parameters](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) it doesn't look like you can, though you can change the position of the whiskers as a fraction of IQR.

Comment: @char I also had the impression, but I wanted to be sure I am not overlooking something. But Even the whiskers don't give me options to customize them much

Comment: You could download the seaborn git repo from [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/36964d7ffba3683de2117d25f224f8ebef015298/seaborn/categorical.py) and edit the file I linked on line 1002, rebuild it and add it. Not sure on the specifics though.

Comment: @char that actually sounds doable, thanks for having a look into it!